# Error Failed to Execute_when trying to join table and Shapefile

Tags: arcpy, attribute-joins, table, error-000732, error-000728

I am trying to join a shpfile w/ an excel document. Both the shpfile and table have the same number of rows with matching "Unique_Joiner" columns.

**Below is the script im running through the IDLE GUI.**

### ArcGIS 10.4 | Python 2.7

```
# script to join all feature attributes in dataset with corresponding table.

# IMPORT SYSTEM MODULES

import arcpy
from arcpy import env

#SET WORKSPACE ENVIRONMENT

env.workspace = (r"P:\Miscellaneous ACi\Project_aci_Geodatabase\Texas\2015\shp")

#SET VARIABLES
table = (r"P:\Miscellaneous ACi\Project_aci_Geodatabase\Texas\2015\tables\Texas_C_ply_2015_table")

dataList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
for data in dataList:
    arcpy.JoinField_management(data, "UNIQUE_JOINER", table, "UNIQUE_JOINER")
```

**and ive been getting kickbacks:**

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "P:\Miscellaneous
>   ACi\Project_aci_Geodatabase\scripts for Luke\3-join.py", line 18, in
>   
>       arcpy.JoinField_management(data, "UNIQUE_JOINER", table, "UNIQUE_JOINER")   File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.4\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 6098, in
>   JoinField
>       raise e ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid. ERROR 000728: Field UNIQUE_JOINER does not exist within table ERROR
>   000732: Join Table: Dataset P:\Miscellaneous
>   ACi\Project_aci_Geodatabase\Texas\2015\tables\Texas_C_ply_2015_table
>   does not exist or is not supported Failed to execute (JoinField).

**Does anyone know why my parameters may be invalid or why the "Unique_Joiner" does not exist within dataset? (My table is saved as .xls).**

Comment: There is no extension/sheet name on your table path variable: "Texas_C_ply_2015_table", for e.g. "Texas_C_ply_2015_table.xls\Sheet$"

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you can join an excel table to a feature unless you first convert it with [Excel To Table](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/excel-to-table.htm):

> Converts Microsoft Excel files into a table